# My Hit Detection in my 2D array is taking out random people instead of the ones it hits

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, comments, collision-detection

Hey so here it is I'm trying to change the initial health to 0 once they are hit. But with this it's changing a random enemy in the 2D array and making them disappear instead of the ones that are hit. I've commented most of my code hope it helps :)
couldn't find a post with the same question sorry if there is... Any other suggestions would be amazing too! Thanks

```
       public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //score & ammo
        int score = 0;
        int ammo = 5;

        //setting cannon
        int tank = 0;

        //mouse cords
        int mouseX = 0;
        int mouseY = 0;

        //Small boom 
        int Sboomx = -20;
        int Sboomy = -20;

        //random positions for enemys to spawn
        int MinX = 1020;
        int MaxX = 7020;
        int MinY = 350;
        int MaxY = 400;

        //speed of them
        int SpeedMinX = -7;
        int SpeedMaxX = -2;

        //array
        int[,] bads = new int[300, 5];
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //setting positions and loading in people
            Random randNum = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
            {
                //where they go
                bads[i,0] = randNum.Next(MinX, MaxX);
                bads[i, 1] = randNum.Next(MinY, MaxY);
                //health
                bads[i, 2] = 1;

                //how they move
                //dx
                bads[i, 3] = randNum.Next(SpeedMinX, SpeedMaxX);
                //dy
                bads[i, 4] = 1;
            }         
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            //background
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.Background1, 0, 0, 1000, 500);

            //Aim
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.crosshair, mouseX - 10, mouseY - 10, 20, 20);

            //explotion
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.small, Sboomx - 285, Sboomy - 298, 600, 600);

            //Tank cannon        
            if (tank == 1)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.Tank__5__copy, 140, 335, 60, 60);
            }
            else if (tank == 2)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.Tank__10__copy, 140, 335, 60, 60);
            }
            else if (tank == 3)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.Tank__15__copy, 140, 335, 60, 60);
            }
            else if (tank == 4)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.Tank_0__copy, 140, 335, 60, 60);
            }

            //draw Bad guys
            for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
            {             
                    if (bads[i, 2] == 1)
                    {
                        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, bads[i, 0] , bads[i, 1], 10, 20);
                    }
            }
            //undrawthem
            for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
            {
                if (bads[i, 2] == 0)
                {
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, bads[i, 0], bads[i, 1], 0, 0);
                    Sboomx = -20;
                    Sboomy = -20;
                }
            }
        }

        //Timer
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Collision 
            for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
            {
                if (Sboomx == bads[i, 0] || Sboomy == bads[i,1])
                {
                    bads[i, 2] = 0;
                    ammo++;
                    score = score + 5; ;
                }
            }

                //Score
            label2.Text = " " + score;

            //Ammo
            label1.Text = " " + ammo;

            //Moving enemys
            for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
            {
                bads[i, 0] = bads[i, 0] + bads[i, 3];
                bads[i, 1] = bads[i, 1] + bads[i, 4];
                if (bads[i, 0] > 2040 || bads[i, 0] < 140)
                {
                    bads[i, 3] = bads[i, 3] * -1;
                }
                if (bads[i, 1] > 335 || bads[i, 1] < 350)
                {
                    bads[i, 4] = bads[i, 4] * -1;
                }
            }
            this.Refresh();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Ammo
        }

        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Customers served
        }

        private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //Control tank cannon
            mouseY = e.Y;
            mouseX = e.X;

            if (mouseY > 350 && mouseY < 375)
            {
                tank = 1;
            }
            else if (mouseY > 376 && mouseY < 390)
            {
                tank = 2;
            }
            else if (mouseY > 391)
            {
                tank = 3;
            }
            else if (mouseY <= 339)
            {
                tank = 4;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //creates explotion and takes away ammo
            Sboomx = e.X;
            Sboomy = e.Y;
            ammo--;
        }

        private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //moves explosion
            Sboomx = -20;
            Sboomy = -20;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Theres too much code here for someone to be expected to help. Try working to produce a minimal reproduduction (incidently doing this will probably help you solve your problem)

Comment: The health status is bads[i,2].  When you are moving the enemys you aren't moving the 2 item in the array so it appears that a random enemy is disappearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood correctly what are you trying to do, then, the problem is in this line:

```
if (Sboomx == bads[i, 0] || Sboomy == bads[i,1])
```

The bad guy is a rectangle, and the bomb is a point, and what you are doing here is trying to match one point of that rectangle with bomb x-coordinate **or** y-coordinate, which is also wrong, you need to check if the bomb coordinates is **inside** that rectangle or not.

Also, it is a good idea to move the "//Collision" loop to `Form1_MouseDown` event to avoid the delay between the mouse click and the timer tick, especially because you reset the bomb coordinates in `Form1_MouseUp` event.

Another thing, "//undrawthem" loop has no logic here, you are drawing a rectangle with 0*0 dimensions (did you think it will resize the existing rectangles?), when you call `Refresh()`, `Invalidate()` get called to make the entire surface invalidate, then `Update()` get called to update invalidate area, so the entire form graphics get cleared and redrawn again when `Form1_Paint` event get raised no matter what was existing before.

You may consider this, instead of using `Refresh()`, use `Invalidate(invalidate_area)` and `Update()`, so you don't refresh the entire surface:

```
Rectangle invalidate_area = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 50);
invalidate_area.Inflate(3, 3); //add extra bounds
Invalidate(invalidate_area);
Update();
```

but if you did so, you will need to take care of dead bad guys, moving bad guys (update old occupied area and the new one) and so on.

Comment: I just started learning C# a couple weeks ago so this helps a lot thanks for the suggestions